# delete parentheses and everything inside with bash

Tags: bash, sed

I need to remove parentheses and all letters inside them, included the symbol '. For example:

```
Ametlla de Mar (L') to Ametlla de Mar
```

I have used sed without success.

Comment: sometimes inside () I have others letters...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo "Ametlla de Mar (L') to Ametlla de Mar" | sed 's/([^)]*)//g'
```

Ametlla de Mar  to Ametlla de Mar